# Change Envelope From to match From header in Postfix

Tags: email, postfix, g-suite, spf

I am using Postfix as a gateway for my domain and need it to change or rewrite the Envelope From address to match the From header. For example, the From: header is "joe@domainA.org" and the Envelope From is "bob@domainB.com". I want Postfix to make the Envelope From "joe@domainA.org" before relaying it on. I took a look at the [Postfix Address Rewriting document](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html) but couldn't find anything that matched my use case.

(In case you're curious why I need to do this: Gmail uses the same Envelope From when sending from a particular account, no matter which From: address you choose to use. I would prefer not to disclose the account being used to send the email. Also, it messes with SPF/DMARC domain alignment - see 4.2.2 of the DMARC draft spec.)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give some examples. So what the headers currently look like and what you're trying to get them to look like.

Comment: did you ever find a working solution for your problem? I have the same question and for much the same reasons...

Comment: I've been wrestling with this for hours tonight, winding up in all kinds of corners of the Internet, trying to figure out how to do this. Literally all I want to do is make Postfix take the From address, whatever it is, and pass it along during sending such that the Return-Path is the same. It seems to be utterly impossible, though I would love to be proved wrong.

Comment: wow, 5 years ago, no real answer, and I'm in the same boat now :(

Comment: How about 9 years later :-(

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want "sender_canonical_maps" (and "recipient_canonical_maps" if you want inbound mail to be translated backwards):

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_canonical_maps

Comment: As far as I can tell, this only implements a table lookup. However, there might be several different From header addresses used with the same Envelope From address, so the table needs to act somewhat dynamically. Is there a variable for the From header address that can be used for the result?

Comment: You could specify a regular expression: http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types

Comment: I don't see a way to do the rewriting dynamically, specifically to rewrite the envelope address based on the 'From:' address  - even using regex or pcre tables...